# Logistic Regression Coefs from SHAP values

Tags: python, shap

I'm trying to get model weights using SHAP values(don't ask why). In my case I consider feature perturbation interventional.

According to this https://shap.readthedocs.io/en/latest/generated/shap.LinearExplainer.html

```
shap_values[i][j] = coef[j] * (X[i][j] - X.mean(0)[j])
```

So it should be

```
coef[j] = shap_values[i][j]/(X[i][j] - X.mean(0)[j])
```

For each row of X(for every i) I get different answer and all of them are wrong(they are close, but not exact). What am I understanding wrong?

Comment: Try with a background data of size not larger than 100.

Comment: Yea, ty. They use np.random.seed(0) and np.random.choice(size=100) if data size is larget than 100.